# Displaying bitmap image from memory in XAML file with C# windows application

Tags: c#, xaml, bitmap

I have an array of Package objects, each has an Icon, which is a byte array but I can change it into a bitmap if needed. These are created at runtime and the icons are fetched at run time, and can be different each time.

I'm new to XAML, and am wondering what the needed code is to display each icon. I Imagine the xaml will look something like this, but am unsure how the xaml.cs code will need to look. Can anyone steer me in the right direction, or provide me with an example?

```
<Image Source="package.Icon" Height="30" Width="30" />
```

Comment: You shouldn't need any code in the code behind.  If you add your icon as a Resource, then it should find it automatically.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I can't, the icons are created after compilation, at the beginning of execution they are fetched from somewhere, and are not always the same. This is why I have to display them from memory.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to make a new property on your class that automatically converts the byte array to one you can bind to readily in XAML:

```
public System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage ImageAsObject
{
        get { return this.YourMethodToConvertByteArrayToBitmapImage(); }
}
```

And then in XAML:

```
Image Source="{Binding ImageAsObject}"
```

Comment: Say I am fetching the package icon based on the name of the package...could I do something like this? With a parameter?

Image Source="{Binding ImageAsObject=packageName}"

Comment: Close - change the sequence: {Binding packagename.object.ImageAsObject} and it should work.